# Why rendering HTML elements with data from array using Array.map() works but from Object using Object.keys().forEach() doesn't?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, object

I am interested to know why this code - rendering HTML elements with data from array using Array.map() - works fine and elements appear on screen:

```
<div className="container">
    {data.map((d) => (
        <div className="item">
            <img 
            src={d.img} 
            alt=""/>
            <h3>{d.title}</h3>
        </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

but this code - rendering HTML elements with data from an object using forEach() - doesn't work and nothing appears on screen although no error is thrown and console.log()'s within `<div className="betCard"></div>` work fine:

```
<div className="container">
    {Object.keys(data).forEach((bet) => (
        <div className="betcard">
            <p>{data[bet]["name"]}</p>
            <p>{data[bet]["oddsDecimal"]}</p>
            <p>{data[bet]["genericName"]}</p>
        </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

Comment: The `.forEach()` method ignores any returned values from its callback function.

Comment: Q: I have a function that works, and another that doesn't work.       A: Use the one that works.

Comment: ""how could I get the second function to work correctly" " um, use map.... not forEach. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a list of results, while [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) always returns `undefined` (so nothing gets passed to React to render).  The latter code could be successfully written as:

```js
<div className="container">
    {Object.keys(data).map((bet) => (
        <div className="betcard">
            <p>{data[bet]["name"]}</p>
            <p>{data[bet]["oddsDecimal"]}</p>
            <p>{data[bet]["genericName"]}</p>
        </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Foreach doesn't return the result, `map` does.

```
{Object.keys(data).map((bet) => (
```

would solve the issue.